# KeyError occurs when I run a Flask application (using flask-sqlalchemy)

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use flask-sqlalchemy to manage my pre-existing mysql database, and I have a table named content. Here is my code snippet.

```
# coding:utf-8
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
...

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://...'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Content(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['content']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<title %r>' % self.title


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run the code above, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Content(db.Model):
  File "hello.py", line 14, in Content
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['content']
KeyError: 'content'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `KeyError` shows you accessing the table as `Content` while the code snippet shows you accessing it as `content` - do both ways cause `KeyError`s?

Comment: @SeanVieira actually i copied the wrong report , i've modified my question.please check out.

Comment: Any reason why you are using `metadata.tables` instead of just using `__table__ = 'content'`?

Comment: @SeanVieira I learned from here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19064993/4144064.

Comment: 1. Are you calling `db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)` before you create the model? 2. Does the `content` table already exist in the DB?

Comment: @SeanVieira no error report anymore when I call do.Model.metadata.reflect(do.engine). Thanks, SeanVieira.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19064993/4144064) you need to call `db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)` before you create the model.  That way the existing table's metadata will be populated in `metadata.tables`.