# flask sqlalchemy example around existing database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**Problem:** there needs to be full working example of auto-mapping sqlalchemy to an existing database in an app with multiple binds.

I want to bind to two databases and have one auto-map the tables.  I need to do this because i don't have control over one DB, thus would have to constantly re-write my models and might delete new tables every time i migrate.

I love the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database), but i can't seem to make it work in Flask (I am able to use the sqlalchemy only to query as per the example).

The model.py I set up from the example above results in

**EDIT**  I pulled the line

```
 db.Model.metadata.reflect[db.engine]
```

from another post, and it should be db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)
very simple solution

**here is my model.py**

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db.Model.metadata.reflect[db.engine]#change to (db.engine)

class Buildings(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['test']
    __bind_key__ = 'chet'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.test1

.... other models from sqlalchemy uri here...
```

i get this

```
>>> from app import db, models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from app import views, models
  File "app/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app,models, db
  File "app/models.py", line 163, in <module>
    db.Model.metadata.reflect[db.engine]
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

**Here's my config.py**

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://chet@localhost/ubuntuweb'

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'chet':        'postgresql://chet@localhost/warehouse',
 }
```

**here's my init.py file**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'app/static'
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

Bootstrap(app)

from app import views, models
admin = Admin(app)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has

```
db.Model.metadata.reflect[db.engine]
```

When it should be

```
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)  # parens not brackets
```

This should have been pretty obvious from the stack trace....

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I pulled the hard brackets out of the link in my post and part of my question is why the answer has brackets.  It was from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database      "bind the declarative base to an engine: db.Model.metadata.reflect[db.engine]"

Comment: @ChetMeinzer because the answer is wrong. I'll edit to correct it now.

Comment: @ChetMeinzer (you'll notice that the top-voted and accepted answer has the correct syntax! :D)

Comment: Ever look for something and it's right under your nose.  spent hours confused-ready to get back to work.  thanks again.

Comment: @ChetMeinzer glad I could help! :)