# accessing existing database in sqlalchemy in flask project + sqlalchemy filter

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

**First:**

I'm working on a flask project and using msql for now, but want to migrate to sqlalchemy. I want to access existing database table using sqlalchemy. Does sqlalchemy have any alternative for something like this

> python manage.py inspectdb > models.py

which we use in django.

I tried to test [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404103/6662140), so my script is like this now:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from itertools import groupby
from flask import request
import MySQLdb
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine("mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydbname")
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
User = Base.classes.p_user
session = Session(engine)
session.commit()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)





@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    result = str(session.query(User).all())
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But the output is like this:

> [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Why? And how I can fix it?

**Second:**

Also how should I use filter for selecting data in my script?

I tried this:

```
result = session.query(User).filter_by(shahr = 'tehran')
```

But this arror raised in terminal:

> TypeError: 'Query' object is not callable

Also tried this one:

```
result = session.query.filter_by(shahr = 'tehran')
```

The error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter_by'

Or tried this one:

```
result = User.query.filter_by(shahr = 'tehran')
```

And the error was:

> AttributeError: type object 'p_user' has no attribute 'query'

Comment: I found the solution myself `sqlacodegen postgresql://postgres:mydbpassword@localhost/mydb --outfile db.py` ... this page helps `https://simpletutorials.com/c/2220/SQLAlchemy+Code+Generation`