# Flask-sqlalchemy connecting to an existing database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to an existing database and I am unsure where to put `db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)` as shown in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database).

My flask app that is structured like:

[image]

I am not sure where to add `db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)`.

In `intel\__init__.py` I am using a function to create app:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app
```

And in my register_extensions function:

```
def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)
    return None
```

in `my model\sam.py`

```
from intel.database import db


class Sam(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['sam_monthly_extract']
```

Now, when I do that I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from intel import create_app
  File "C:\Users\spitf\G2XChange\intel_app\intel\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from intel.views.sam_view import sam_blueprint
  File "C:\Users\spitf\G2XChange\intel_app\intel\views\sam_view.py", line 3, in <module>
    from intel.models.sam import Sam
  File "C:\Users\spitf\G2XChange\intel_app\intel\models\sam.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Sam(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\spitf\G2XChange\intel_app\intel\models\sam.py", line 5, in Sam
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['sam_monthly_extract']
KeyError: 'sam_monthly_extract'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

`run.py`

```
from intel import create_app

app = create_app()
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you have __sam_monthly_extract__ table?

Comment: What is your run.py? post that code

Comment: yes, the table is there.

Comment: Make sure you only `import sam` after you call `db.Model.metadata.reflect()`. Your import statement does not have to be at the top of the file.

Comment: I use my Sam model in a the sam_blueprint, which is in `intel\views`

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question in my search for an answer to the same exact problem and since it helped me actually get there, I had to make sure to come back and provide you with what helped solve my issue.

What I *think* was happening was that the `__init__.py` that contained the application factory was imported from my run.py and so was the import of the models.py which was at the bottom of the `__init__` file, which imported before I could run the function to create the app and not having any context from which to pull that table from. That's at least the best I can explain it currently.

What solved it for me was to move the models import into the application factory, explicitly under the app context, right after db.init_app() like so:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)
        from app import models
```

Not sure if that is the best way to do it, but it's been working for me ever since.