# Flask sqlAlchemy: Creating models for the existing database structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlAlchemy and I wonder if there is a way create a class that would be mapped to the existing table in DB without specifying any columns of the table (but all columns could be accessed as attributes of the object)?

Comment: Check out this:
[build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database)

Comment: Have a look at the automap extension: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html

Comment: Also have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652937/how-to-build-a-flask-application-around-an-already-existing-database?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I generated models for flask-sqlalchemy which use MS SQL.

```
flask-sqlacodegen --flask mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<server>/<database> --tables <table_names>> db_name.py
```

you have to install flask-sqlacodegen and pymssql though.

Comment: I found this solution particularly idiotproof. A single look at pypi and I had the full database modeled out less than one minute later

Answer (score 0):

Have recently came across this issue. Try steps below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

class User(object): # class which can can act as ORM class
    pass

dbPath = 'places.sqlite'
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % dbPath, echo=True) # create engine

metadata = MetaData(engine)
user_table= Table('user_existing_class', metadata, autoload=True) # create a Table object
mapper(User, user_table) # map Table to ORM class

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
res = session.query(User).all()
res[1].name
```

Comment: Declarative is usually preferred over classical mapping these days, though there's nothing wrong with the latter. Just that it might look a bit odd to many who then read various other tutorials etc.